# Vuejs and Chart libraries

Tags: asynchronous, charts, vue.js

I'm trying to make the application with vuejs and chart libraries. However, I got the problem when I link this chart with my database (Elasticsearch).

```
//elasticsearch.js

var output = {}
$.post('http://localhost:9200/index/_search', JSON.stringify({

   // query section
}), function (result) {

  // handling results and push to the output

}, 'json');


export{output}
```

Here is my vue component

```
<template>
    <chart :options="pie" ref="pie" auto-resize></chart>
</template>

<script>
    import {output} from './elasticsearch.js'

export default {
    ...

    data = [
        {value: output.pos, name: 'positive'}
        ...
    ]    

}
```

However, When I refresh the application, chart said value is undefined. I think it is because chart was rendering before finishing execution of js file.

In this case, is there any way to import js file asynchronously? or any other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how you are drawing your chart, but you can use [vue-chartjs](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs) which should make it easier to get charts running because it's designed specifically for use with vue.

Comment: post your code in chart component

Comment: I fix this by `set the data in function(result)`